# How to convert varchar to timestamp in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, varchar

I have data as following, But the column type is Varchar:

```
2019-09-28T23:59:59.52Z
```

I assume 52 here is milli seconds, If so..

I would like to convert it as following and change the column type to timestamp:

```
2019-09-28 23:59:59.52
```

Can someone let me know how I can convert  in postgreSQL?

EDIT:
I can see data in table as (since the column type is varchar):

```
2019-09-28T23:59:59.52Z
```

Instead, I want data in the table to be shown as:

```
2019-09-28 23:59:59        ( and may be .52, if possible)
```

I need to change the column type to timestamp as well, I guess, Please help with that too.

Answer:

Tim has provided a solution, You can follow that.

But, In my case, It is prod env, So, I have just changed the type using:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE TIMESTAMP USING my_column::timestamp without time zone;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp string literal is already in a format which can be directly cast in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT '2019-09-28T23:59:59.52Z'::timestamp;  -- 2019-09-28 23:59:59.52
```

As a test, let's add one day to make sure it's working:

```sql
SELECT '2019-09-28T23:59:59.52Z'::timestamp + interval '1 day';
-- 2019-09-29 23:59:59.52
```

If you want to actually add a new timestamp column using string data from another column, then try:

```sql
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN new_ts TIMESTAMP;

UPDATE yourTable SET new_ts = old_ts::timestamp;

ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP COLUMN old_ts;
ALTER TABLE yourTable RENAME COLUMN new_ts TO old_ts;  -- optional
```

The last `ALTER` statement is optional if you want the new bona fide timestamp column to bear the same name as the old text timestamp column.

Comment: You're right. But the thing is, The column type is 'varchar' and I want the data in table as timestamp.

Comment: I don't want to add new column, I just want to change the current column's type & show the data as required. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Also, For your information, The data is coming into this table from AWS Lambda as a string. So, If we change the current column type in table from varchar to timestamp, Will the operation be successful?

Comment: @Jack It should work without issues if all the timestamp data be valid.  Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have altered the column type as mentioned. It did work! :)

Comment: I have reverted to the option of creating a new column.  Give that a try in this case.